# Make Specific Columns of QTableView readonly with QStandardItemModel

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QTableView with its model which is QStandardItemModel. How can i make specific columns in tableView readOnly? It seems that i can't alter edit triggers of tableView since i want specific columns to be editable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to set `QStandardItem::setFlags()` for each item in that column, excluding `Qt::ItemIsEditable` flag. For example:

```
[..]
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem;
item->setFlags(Qt::NoItemFlags);
[..]
```

Comment: Thanks, 1) how can i exclude flag from Item 2) note that i'm using a delegate on tableview

Comment: I've tried this: item->flags() &- Qt::ItemIsEditable. but it won't works. (maybe its because of delegate)

Comment: It's better to explicitly remove only the flag you want to remove, not all of them: `item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable)`.

Comment: @Mosi : your try didn't work because `-2 != ~2`. You effectively removed `Qt::ItemIsSelectable` instead of `Qt::ItemIsEditable`.